# Administrator Authenticate as User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor, ef-database-first

I am building a Visual Studio C# Web application with the MVC framework.

I have set up my users and roles etc with the Website Administration tool.

I wish for sales staff to be able to shop / checkout on behalf of customers.

As such, I wish to be able to allow sales staff to authenticate as a user (e.g. log into a user's account) without password.

Moving on from this, I wish to be able to log back into the sales staff account easily.

Is this possible, how do I enable this functionality?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using the membership provider?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like this before but only in Web Forms which was based on this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43724/ASP-NET-Forms-authentication-user-impersonation

Not sure if this will work in MVC but if you look at the comments it would appear someone has at least made an attempt so you may be able to get it to work.